# Select Form to Bootstrap jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form for a switch-styler system

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
  <input type="submit" name="switchstyle" value="Changer de style" />
  <select name="css">
    <option value="meteobell">Météobell</option>
    <option value="noir">Sombre</option>
    <option value="blanc">Blanc</option>
    <option value="alternance">Jour Blanc / Nuit Sombre</option>
  </select>
```

but I have since gone through a menu in jQuery bootstrap and would like to change it in this form:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu ">
  <form name="switchstyle" id="switchstyle" method="post" action="index.php">
    <input type="hidden"  name="css" id="css" value="" />
    <li >
      <a href="#" data-value="meteobell"   data-target="#sidebar-left" data-toggle="push">
        Météobell
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-value="noir" data-target="#sidebar-left" data-toggle="push">
        Sombre
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-value="blanc"  data-target="#sidebar-left" data-toggle="push">
        Blanc
      </a>
    </li>

    <li >
      <a href="#" data-value="alternance" data-target="#sidebar-left" data-toggle="push">
        Jour Blanc / Nuit Sombre
      </a>
    </li>               
  </form>   
</ul>

<script>
  $(function() {    
    $('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function() {
      $('#css').val($(this).data('value'));
      $('#switchstyle').submit();
    });
  });
</script>
```

and obviously it does not work. Here the PHP code from the style switcher, but the problem is not here.

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST['switchstyle']))
{
    if(file_exists("./css/".$_POST['css'].".css") 
    {
        setcookie('css', $_POST['css'], time()+(365*24*3600));
        $switchcss = $_POST['css'];
    }

}
elseif(isset($_COOKIE['css']))
{
    $switchcss = $_COOKIE['css'];
}   
else
{
    $switchcss = "meteobell";
}
?>
```

In fact I want only submit the data-value in a $_POST, but not in a first form select html. I want submit my $_POST value with the Bootsrap dropdown-menu.

Comment: Please be more specific than "does not work." It is not clear from your code example exactly what you are trying to do, or what is going wrong.

Comment: I want submit the data-value in a form with the dropdown-menu from bootstrap. Here the PHP code from the style switcher : `<?PHP
if(isset($_POST['switchstyle']))
{
 if((file_exists("./css/".$_POST['css'].".css") || ($_POST['css'] = 'alternance')))
 {
  setcookie('css', $_POST['css'], time()+(365*24*3600));
  $switchcss = $_POST['css'];
 }
 
}
elseif(isset($_COOKIE['css']))
{
 $switchcss = $_COOKIE['css'];
} 
else
{
 $switchcss = "meteobell";
}
?>`

Comment: Please edit that into your original question; it's very difficult to read as a comment

Comment: Ok I have edit. Sorry, English, is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

In the PHP code replace:

```
if (isset ($ _ POST ['switchstyle']))
```

by

```
  if (isset ($ _ POST [ 'css']))
```

We then shifts the name = "css" from the select to the input:

```
<form id = "switchstyle" method = "POST" action = "index.php">
             <input id = "css" name = "css" type = "hidden">
```

and we add an onclick in the link by removing the href = "#" (otherwise it not works):

```
<li>
<a onclick="$('#css').val('meteobell'); $('#switchstyle').submit()" data-target="#sidebar-left" data-toggle="push">
Météobell
</a>
</ li>
```

If it can save others time ...